# Angular service not assigning value to empty object

Tags: angularjs

I have a service:

```
storeApp.service('currentCustomer',function($http) {
    this.customerID = 0;
    this.customerInfo = {}
    this.customerAttributes = {}
    this.getCustomerInfo = function () {
        if (this.customerID != 0) {
            $http.get('/customers/' + this.customerID).
            then(function (result) {
                this.customerInfo = result.data[0]
            })
        }
    }
```

and a controller:

```
storeApp.controller('storeList',function($scope,$http,currentCustomer) {
    $scope.changeCust = function changeCust(id) {
        currentCustomer.customerID = id;
        currentCustomer.getCustomerInfo()
        console.log("After Change customer:")
        console.log(currentCustomer)
    }
    $scope.selectedStore = currentCustomer
});
```

If I try to access selectedStore.customerID, I get values.

If I try to access selectedStore.customerInfo, I get an empty array, even though when i put console logging in to check the values, it says they are assigned.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually assigning a value to `CustomerId`, and your service method is assigning a value to `customerInfo`. Except `this` in the service method, is not the same as `this` in the service. You should instantiate a `var self = this;` reference inside the service and use this value in all your object manipulation. eg: `self.customerInfo = ....`

Comment: thanks. Does `this` refer to the method itself then? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think this article does a nice job of explaining context in JavaScript: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Your reference for `this` has been changed inside function. first store `this` reference in some variable and then assign properties, some prefer to use the word `self` but I prefer `service`

```
storeApp.service('currentCustomer',function($http) {
   var service = this;
   service.customerID = 0;
   service.customerInfo = {}
   service.customerAttributes = {}
   service.getCustomerInfo = function () {
      if (service.customerID != 0) {
          $http.get('/customers/' + this.customerID).
          then(function (result) {
              service.customerInfo = result.data[0]
          });
    }
}
```